# android how to center a TextView within the full width of the parent?

Tags: android-recyclerview, cardview

I have a Checkbox and a TextView that are anchored to the left side of a UI.  I have another TextView "newcard #" that I would like to center in the full width of the parent.  The parent width is the white space running from left to right, shown below.  Notice how "newcard #" is to the right of the red center line.  Basically I would like "newcard #" to be centered around the red center line.

[image]

I have tried multiple combinations of gravity and layout_gravity without any luck.  What am I missing here?

item.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
card_view:cardElevation="4dp" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"  >

<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#008080"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardType1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:paddingStart="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingEnd="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardType1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cardType1"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFlLabelFinal"
        android:textStyle="bold"            
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"  />
```

Comment: In the second TextView you should use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`.

Comment: I tried that as well.  "newcard #" in that case ends up positioned just to the right of the "Work" TextView.

Comment: Have you deleted layout_toRightOf and layout_toEndOf?

Comment: I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kept only RelativeLayout, hope a result won't change.
Deleted:

```
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cardType1"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardType1"
```

and inserted:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

So:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="#008080"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardType1"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingEnd="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingStart="3dp"
        tools:text="Work"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText1"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        tools:text="newcard#"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFlLabelFinal"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankTextNumsTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="fggfhfg"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cardBlankText1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I deleted layout_toRightOf and layout_toEndOf and added gravity="center" or gravity="center_horizontal" and all looks good!  Answer accepted and voted.  Cheers!

Comment: One minor issue.  The TextView "cardBlankTextNumsTotal" is not showing to the right of the centered "cardBlankText1".  I did try removing the layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardBlankText1" and layout_toEndOf="@+id/cardBlankText1" with no luck.  Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Maybe you should set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to the cardBlankText1 TextView?

Comment: Thank you very much for accepting the answer. You should set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to the cardBlankText1 TextView. I tried to add a TextView called cardBlankTextNumsTotal and it is shown to the right of the cardBlankText1. See the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick.  Otherwise, the second TextView is pushed to the right of the entire parent so it won't be seen.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for your words. Yes, RelativeLayout has some difficulties, it can shift too far some elements, even hide them. If you wish to show all, you should draw on a paper how it will look like. And maybe use other layouts, not only RelativeLayout.

Comment: Ah yes, good advice.  I am trying to solve one other problem in a Recyclerview.  If you're up for another, I loaded a new question at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739404/android-recyclerview-how-do-i-programmtically-select-textview-background-color